# ContextMenu in WPF is too wide

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I've got a problem with my ContextMenu in WPF. The menu is far too wide- it's the width of the items I put on it, plus about fifty-a hundred pixels. So when you open the menu, instead of being a clean list of options or buttons, there's loads of greyspace on each side. How can I fix this?

Edit: Here's my XAML for the menu:

```
<ContextMenu Padding="0">
    <Button Content="Close Tab" Height="23" Name="closetabbutton" Width="75" Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="closetabbutton_Click" />
    <TextBox Height="23" Name="renamebox" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="True" TextChanged="renamebox_TextChanged" />
    <Button Content="Close Menu" Height="23" Name="closemenubutton" Width="75" Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="closemenubutton_Click" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: That seems like an unusual way to use a context menu from a usability perspective. Usually you would add MenuItems to a ContextMenu, not buttons.

Comment: @chibacity: There are MenuItems? If I change it to MenuItem, then the text won't show up, even though I changed the Content property to the Header property.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer for a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is reserved for icons on the left, and input gesture text (e.g. Ctrl+C) on the right. This is by design.

If you wish to change this, you'll have to create your own ContextMenu style. Here's an example of how to do this:

http://www.dev102.com/2008/06/20/how-to-create-a-wpf-custom-context-menu/

**Update**

Further to my question comment, MenuItems would normally be used where you have used buttons. For example:

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Name="mnuClose" Header="Close tab" InputGestureText="Ctrl+C" />
        <MenuItem Name="mnuRename">
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <TextBox Name="txtRename" Width="100" />
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Do I have to write my own code to recognize the InputGestureText?

Comment: @DeadMG InputGestureText is for display purposes only and is designed to be used when you are manually hooking gestures up. If you bind a RoutedCommand to a menu item and it has a KeyGesture then the menu item will automatically get the gesture text. It's quite a complicated topic unfortunately.

Comment: I understand it's been 10 years since this was last touched, but the link is broken now

Comment: Hence the reason links have been 'discouraged' here